# Percentage change with groupby python

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
Year    Month   Booked
0   2016    Aug 55999.0
6   2017    Aug 60862.0
1   2016    Jul 54062.0
7   2017    Jul 58417.0
2   2016    Jun 42044.0
8   2017    Jun 48767.0
3   2016    May 39676.0
9   2017    May 40986.0
4   2016    Oct 39593.0
10  2017    Oct 41439.0
5   2016    Sep 49677.0
11  2017    Sep 53969.0
```

I want to obtain the percentage change with respect to the same month from last year. I have tried the following code:

```
df['pct_ch'] = df.groupby(['Month','Year'])['Booked'].pct_change()
```

but I get the following, which is not at all what I want:

```
Year    Month   Booked  pct_ch
0   2016    Aug 55999.0 NaN
6   2017    Aug 60862.0 0.086841
1   2016    Jul 54062.0 -0.111728
7   2017    Jul 58417.0 0.080556
2   2016    Jun 42044.0 -0.280278
8   2017    Jun 48767.0 0.159904
3   2016    May 39676.0 -0.186417
9   2017    May 40986.0 0.033017
4   2016    Oct 39593.0 -0.033987
10  2017    Oct 41439.0 0.046624
5   2016    Sep 49677.0 0.198798
11  2017    Sep 53969.0 0.086398
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not `groupby` *Year* otherwise you won't get, for instance, `Aug 2017` and `Aug 2016` together. Also, use `transform` to broadcast back results to original indices

Try:

```
df['pct_ch'] = df.groupby(['Month'])['Booked'].transform(lambda s: s.pct_change())

    Year    Month   Booked  pct_ch
0   2016    Aug     55999.0 NaN
6   2017    Aug     60862.0 0.086841
1   2016    Jul     54062.0 NaN
7   2017    Jul     58417.0 0.080556
2   2016    Jun     42044.0 NaN
8   2017    Jun     48767.0 0.159904
3   2016    May     39676.0 NaN
9   2017    May     40986.0 0.033017
4   2016    Oct     39593.0 NaN
10  2017    Oct     41439.0 0.046624
5   2016    Sep     49677.0 NaN
11  2017    Sep     53969.0 0.086398
```